# I'm trying to check if a word is abecedarian using compareTo

Tags: java, string, loops, compareto

I would like to keep my program pretty much the same.
I've used a lot of String methods like `charAt`, `substring` and `indexOf`.
A word is said to be “abecedarian” if the letters in the word appear in alphabetical order.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Abecedarian{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        String word=getWord();

    }

    public static String getWord(){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word;
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        word=keyboard.nextLine();
        return word;
    }

    public static boolean isAbecedarian(String word){
```

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over the characters in the word and make sure they are in ascending alphabetical order:

```
public static boolean isAbecedarian (String word) {
    int length = word.size();
    if (length <= 1) {
        return true;
    }

    word = word.toLowerCase(); // just in case

    char prev; 
    char curr;

    for (int i = 1; i < length; ++i) {
        prev = word.charAt(i - 1);
        curr = word.charAt(0);
        if (prev > curr) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
if (word.compareTo("abecedarian") == 0) {
   //yes it is equal
}
```

There's better way of checking for equality using `equals` method of String like:

```
if ("abecedarian".equals(word)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: wow, i was actually googling looking for the definition of abecedarian as I thought the questioner was looking for some property of a word, not literally the string 'abecedarian'. Makes sense now

Comment: To quote the OP "A word is said to be “abecedarian” if the letters in the word appear in alphabetical order."

Comment: Yeah sorry, i meant to explain what abecedarian is at first, but i forgot